# how to stop a running startx on linux. Not just changing inittab or init3

Tags: linux, redhat

i am using rhel5 / rhel6 and i would like know how to "stop startx".
i have google this issue and most of the solutions are change inittab to 5, or init 3 etc.

For example, after the server boot up as runlevel 3, then someone run startx and the server is now listening on port 6000.
changing the inittab(requires reboot,which is not an option,and i still able to type startx after that) and `init 3` does not actually solve the problem, the server is still listening on port 6000, and the GUI is still there.

May i know is there any command to actually "stop startx", so that i can run `startx -- -nolisten tcp`

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to keep in mind when shutting it down:

- You need the X server itself to be shut down cleanly such that you don't leave the graphics hardware in an undefined state.
- You need to consider if anything running in the X session needs to be shut down cleanly before the X server is shut down.

The X server and the first process in the session will both have been started by `xinit`. Once the first process in the session dies, `xinit` will take care of shutting down the X server. So if you find that process and kill it, the X server should be gone shortly after as well.

I would use this command to find the processes running in the X session:

```
ps -fA --forest | less
```

You can also just kill the X server directly by sending a SIGTERM signal to it. It will then shut down cleanly and all remaining clients will lose their connection.

For reference, this is the code which `xinit` will run when the first process in the X session has died:

```
static void
shutdown(void)
{
    /* have kept display opened, so close it now */
    if (clientpid > 0) {
        XSetIOErrorHandler(ignorexio);
        if (! setjmp(close_env)) {
            XCloseDisplay(xd);
        }

        /* HUP all local clients to allow them to clean up */
        if (killpg(clientpid, SIGHUP) < 0 && errno != ESRCH)
            Error("can't send HUP to process group %d", clientpid);
    }

    if (serverpid < 0)
        return;

    if (killpg(serverpid, SIGTERM) < 0) {
        if (errno == ESRCH)
            return;
        Fatal("can't kill X server");
    }

    if (!processTimeout(10, "X server to shut down"))
        return;

    Errorx("X server slow to shut down, sending KILL signal");

    if (killpg(serverpid, SIGKILL) < 0) {
        if (errno == ESRCH)
            return;
        Error("can't SIGKILL X server");
    }

    if (processTimeout(3, "server to die"))
        Fatalx("X server refuses to die");
}
```

Comment: I always go straight for the X server, and haven't had problems with that approach.  +1 from me!

Comment: thanks alot mate.  though it took me awhile to actually find the "first process". both of the method worked. also you taught me the sigterm thing.. i didnt know kill -15 is sigterm,which is ctrl+c until i google it. hueheeh thanks <3